# calling stored procedure with JDBC

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, jdbc

I am using MS SqlServer and having a stored procedure that takes start date and end date as parameters, works with bunch of data and writes custom records to a table.  Stored procedure works fine as needed - I checked in SQLServer Management studio.  However, when I Do it java, it is not working.  I get no errors, no exception.  There are just no records written.  so, I assume there is a consumed exceptions somewhere.

Can anyone help with it?  Here is the code:

```
  public static void main(String[] args){
     System.setProperty("oss.property.file.location", "C:\\config.prp");
     Session session = HibernateUtil.getRoSession() ; //works OK
     String start = "2013-11-01", end="2013-11-05" ;

    Connection connection = null;
        CallableStatement statement = null;
        try{
            connection = session.connection() ;

statement = connection.prepareCall("{ ? = call  dbo.sp_getReport(?,?) }");
            statement.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER);
            statement.setDate(2, Date.valueOf(start));
            statement.setDate(3, Date.valueOf(end));

            boolean flag = statement.execute();
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        finally{
            try{
                statement.close();
            }catch(Exception e){
            }
            try{
                connection.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
            }
        }
}
```

I checked with the debugger - inspected the session variable.  It has a proper connection attributes - server, user name, password, etc..

Thanks

Comment: Looks like your sp returns some value.  Did you bother to check it?

Comment: It returns 0 .. but I don't really need it.  It is the results in a table which are of interest

Comment: Are there any problems with value being returned?

Comment: The "? = " at the beginning looks suspicious to me.  All the examples that I find use registerOutParameter in reference to parameters to the stored procedures not as the return value.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I have solved the problem - without the use of a table to write - simply returning dataset from stored proc and then using hibernate call to named query - it didn't work before, probably due to some error I was making.  Can't say what, but I retraced the steps needed and it works now.

Comment: I suspect you have to commit the transaction?

Comment: Lukas, yes - that was it.  That was how I solved it.  There was two hibernate configuration files in a project, and a property was getting overridden.  Thanks